Display becomes jittery ocassionally for a few seconds
Using an Acer nitro an515-31 laptop which has NVIDIA graphic card. OS is Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. System and display driver details are visible in the screenshots.
The issue is that suddenly the display will start shaking and breaking. This stops (I think) if I move the mouse. The occurrence is random and brief, so cannot take a screenshot of it happening, though will try to get one. This was not visible in the 22.10 I had earlier. Have the latest NVDIA driver as of date, but not sure if it is loading as the system info is showing different values.


